# Undefined Input() from Button in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a component within the directory of another component and am trying to get the parent's id value to the child. However, I seem to be unable to get the "string" that I will convert to a number within the child component. Since I am still learning I tried to implement it with examples but had no luck.

Parent Component TS

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiserviceService } from '../service/service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent {
  id : any;
  list : any;
  
  constructor(private _apiservice: ApiserviceService, private router: Router) {} //For rest of code

  setId(idHTML: number) {
    console.log(idHTML); // Works, Typeof returns number
    this.id = idHtml.toString(); // Change to String
    this.router.navigate(['/child']);
  }
}
```

Parent HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="outer-container">
    <div *ngFor="let index of list">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img class="background" src="{{index.poster_path}}">
        <img class="poster" src="{{index.poster_path}}">
        <p class="title">{{index.title}}</p>
        <p class="context">{{index.overview}}</p>
        <button class="button" type="submit" 
          (click)="setId(index.id)">
          Details
        </button>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<app-child [getId]="id"></app-child>
```

Child Component TS

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() getId: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.getId);
  }
}
```

Is my logic of Input wrong? Do I need to send parent's id to the app.component.ts first and then retrieve it back to the child component in getId?

Comment: your code looks valid. be aware that `ngOnInit` is only executed once when the component loads. if you change the id after that, it won't execute but the value of its input will change as expected. if you wish to invoke a logic when the input changes, you can opt to `ngOnChanges` or @Input setter

Comment: So if I just use an interpolation in the child's html, which I do to check if I get the value, it should appear in the view right?
Edit: I have no idea why its getting a undefined :(

Comment: Would there be any case in Angular where Api or Router could interfere with the Input? In case that I might need to check the rest of my code for this issue?

Comment: @BeginnerCoder In the template, I see like your child component is outside of body. Is this typo?

Answer (score 1):

At the time the child component is initialized `getId` property is not defined. So when you call this on `ngOnInit` it will throw an error.

What you can do is you can move it to `ngOnChanges()`.

Example

```
# Add SimpleChanges to the import
import { Component, Input, SimpleChanges, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';


ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(changes.getId) {
        console.log(this.getId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried using the service to make it work but I feel that your solution might be a lot easier. Lemme try it out!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure that you can use a component as a child and then want to navigate to it just doesn't makes sense.

are you trying one of these:

1. in a list when you click on an item you get that item id and go to its details or show its details in something? what you can do is, pass the id using route in htlm.

   <button (click)="viewCustomer(orderData?.customer?.id)" class="btn btn-xs" type="button">
   viewCustomer(id){
   this.location.navigateByUrl('/app/customers/view/' + id);
   }

or you can pass it like

```
<a class="btn btn-white-view" [routerLink]="['/app/customers/view/',orderData?.customer?.id]">view</a>
```

in your other component you can access the passed id via activated route

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params) => {
    this.currentId = params.get('id');
  });
```

For what I think your problem is this should work for you if not, come in the comments and we will figure it out.

Another way to do this is to pass data in the router file where you are defining the routes,
OR
you can set you data in a windows history state property and retrieve it, although the method is identical but here you can send more then just an id.

```
navigateWithState() {
this.router.navigateByUrl('/123', { state: { hello: 'world' } });
```

}
OR
<a routerLink="/details" [state]="{ hello: 'world' }">Go
get it using

```
this.state$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap
  .pipe(map(() => window.history.state))
```

2. if you just want to pass data to a component that is inside your component. like a model or a component below or somewhere on the screen don't use navigation just use input and you will get the data as you have done in your example jus exclude the whole navigation stuff.

If none work or you can't understand something, we can discuss and work through it.